# MySQL Datetime add days

Tags: mysql

How to add days on date time in MySQL like an example below? (Really sorry for my bad english I don't know how to explain.)

Example :

**TABLE member**

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name |     expiry_date     |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | A    | 2016-02-09 09:20:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

If Member A buy a package for 7 days `expiry_date` should be like:

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name |     expiry_date     |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | A    | 2016-02-16 09:20:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

After two days (11th Feb) the package will expire in 5 days, Then Member A buy a package for 7 days again `expiry_date` should be like:

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name |     expiry_date     |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | A    | 2016-02-23 09:20:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

Now package will expire in 12 days (5+7).

**I've tried with my code:**

```
UPDATE member SET expiry_date = now() + INTERVAL 7 DAY WHERE id = 1
```

But it's always set by current date time and + 7 days like:

If today is `2016-02-11 09:20:00` When I run my code `expiry_date` will set date time from `2016-02-11 09:20:00` (current date time) to `2016-02-18 09:20:00`.

But I want it to set date time from `2016-02-16 09:20:00` to `2016-02-23 09:20:00` like my example above.

Comment: if a member buys package for x  days more then new expiry_date would be current expiry_date + x days. right? but you are adding with now()

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu yesss

Comment: then try this `UPDATE member SET expiry_date = expiry_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY WHERE id = 1`

Comment: try to use UPDATE member SET expiry_date = expiry_date  + INTERVAL 7 DAY WHERE id = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to increase the date that is saved in your table, not the date happening right now. Instead of using `NOW()` you should use the column name, i.e. `expiry_date`.

There are two ways of doing this. The first is, as Vipin Jain pointed out, you may use `DATE_ADD`. But instead, use your column name:

```
UPDATE member SET expiry_date = DATE_ADD(expiry_date , INTERVAL 7 DAY) WHERE id = 1;
```

or you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE member SET expiry_date = expiry_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UPDATE member 
SET expiry_date = DATE_ADD(expiry_date , INTERVAL 7 DAY)
WHERE id = 1;
```

for more info https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: @VintageBeef you should use `expiry_date` instead of `now()` as I pointed out in my answer